# Как определить название функции с помощью строки из списка?

Tags: python

Как определить название функции с помощью строки из списка?

```
listname = ["first", "second"]

def listname[0]():
    (...)
```

После этого появляется ошибка

```
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

Что нужно сделать что бы это было возможно? Я возможно тупой и что-то не так делаю либо такой возможности не существует?

Comment: для каких целей это ?

Comment: совершенно не понятно, зачем это может быть нужно в принципе...

Comment: pep8 Function and Variable Names:
Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Comment: Вы определяете название функции ключевым словом после def.тоесть:
def listname(): #listname это название данной функции Переформулируйте вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы сделать функцию с названием из списка можно использовать `exec()`
Вот пример:

```
listname = ("first", "second")

for funcname in listname:
    exec(f"""def {funcname}():
        print("{funcname}")""")
```

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку в питоне всё является переменными, в том числе имена функций, то можно сделать, к примеру, так. Описать функцию с произвольным названием, а потом дать на неё ссылку с помощью переменной, которую вы можете уже назвать как хотите:

```
listname = ["first", "second"]

def tempFunc():
    print("I'm the function!")

globals()[listname[0]] = tempFunc
print(first())
```

Вывод:

```
I'm the function!
```